# Is datetime data in Pandas supposed to be in the index?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

By *supposed to*, what I mean is
*Is that the way Pandas is designed?*, *Are all Pandas time series functions built upon that assumption?*

A few weeks ago I was experimenting with [pandas.rolling_mean](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html) which seemed to want the datetime to be in the index.

Given a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['23/10/2017', '24/10/2017', '25/10/2017','26/10/2017','27/10/2017'], 'dax-close' : [13003.14, 13013.19, 12953.41,13133.28,13217.54]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df
```

[image: datetime as column]

...is it important to always do this:

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df
```

[image: datetime as index]

...as one of the first steps of an analysis?

Comment: By definition a timeSeries implies that that the index is a `DatetimeIndex`, check the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html)

Comment: Thanks, looks like Pandas has at least two kinds of Index types. `type(df.index)` for the first DataFrame above gives `pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex` and `pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex`, would agree that the second type is probably better for time series, otherwise you're not using Pandas functionality properly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is usually timeseries data has date as a DatetimeIndex. and many pandas functions do make use of that e.g. [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) is a big one.

That said, you don't need to have Dates as an index, for example you may even have multiple Datetime columns, then you're out of luck calling the vanilla resample... however you can use [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) to define the "resample" on a column (or as part of a larger/multi-column groupby)

```
In [11]: df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="2D")).sum()
Out[11]:
            dax-close
date
2017-10-23   26016.33
2017-10-25   26086.69
2017-10-27   13217.54

In [12]: df.set_index("date").resample("2D").sum()
Out[12]:
            dax-close
date
2017-10-23   26016.33
2017-10-25   26086.69
2017-10-27   13217.54
```

The former gives more flexibility in that you can groupby multiple columns:

```
In [21]: df["X"] = list("AABAC")

In [22]: df.groupby(["X", pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="2D")]).sum()
Out[22]:
              dax-close
X date
A 2017-10-23   26016.33
  2017-10-25   13133.28
B 2017-10-25   12953.41
C 2017-10-27   13217.54
```